# How to test the text inside a styled component in react native using jest + enzyme

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a custom text component styled using styled components.

```
<P compact name="addNewTitle" small helper>
                      {addNew
                        ? 'Fill in the address details'
                        : 'Tap here to add a new address'}
                    </P>
```

And i want to test the text inside that component and i have wrote this test

```
test('for the title if add new prop is false', () => {
     wrapper = shallow(<Address {...props} />)
     const value = wrapper.find('[name="addNewTitle"]')
     expect(value.length).toBe(1)
     expect(value.text())).toEqual('Tap here to add a new address')
    })
```

But the test throw a error like this

```
 expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      "Tap here to add a new address"
    Received:
      "<Styled(_default) />"
```

How can i overcome this issue and what is wrong in my code .
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As per the [official documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.html)

> text(): Returns a string of the rendered text of the current render tree. This function should be looked at with skepticism if being used to test what the actual HTML output of the component will be. If that is what you would like to test, use enzyme's render function instead.

In your case, you should try the [workaround as given by Enzyme's developer](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/692#issuecomment-261397903)
`expect(wrapper.find('[name="addNewTitle"]').render().text()).toEqual('Tap here to add a new address')`